# Unknown Format error with respond_to in Rails. Correctly trying to implementing polling-to-update

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, view, controller

Hi I'm totally stuck on this and looking for some help.

When I do a show on my object `simulation` I want some javascript to start polling every ten seconds, to call `simulation#update` asynchronously.

I want to do this by `respond_to`, as such:

```
def show
    @simulation = Simulation.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to simulation_url } # This causes problems
    end
end
```

So I would have a `update.js.erb` that does something along the lines of (sorry for the coffeescript)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/simulations/#{params}"
}) 

$('#sim_div').html("<%= j (render @simulation) %>");

setTimeout(callUpdate, 10000)
return
```

I can't get this javascript partial to be called if I include the `format.html` the javascript doesnt get run and I get a format error, and if I do include that line, then I get a unknown format error.

Whats the correct way to go about this? I've tried tons of solutions using coffeescript in the asset pipeline and weird includes and inline javascript to no adue.

For clarity my view is:

```
<%= render 'simulation' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', simulations_path %>
```

and the partial that the script and view loads is:

```
<div id="sim_div">
  <h1><%= @simulation.identifier %></h1>
  <h4 class="offset-col-sm-1">Dimensions: <%= @simulation.x_size %>x<%= @simulation.y_size %></h4>
  <h4 class="offset-col-sm-1">Verdict: <%= @simulation.verdict %></h4>

  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @simulation.state.each do |row| %>
        <tr>
        <% row.each do |current| %>        
            <td class="text-center"><%= current %></td>        
          <% end%>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a shortcut like `respond_to :html, :js` and see if that clears it up. Otherwise try something more explicit:

```
def show
  @simulation = Simulation.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render: "some view"}
    format.html { redirect_to simulation_url }
  end
end
```

`format.js` in the `:show` action will by default render `show.js.erb` when show is called with ajax. The html response will be a redirect.

[This](http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/11/03/respond-to-without-all-the-pain/) blog post may be helpful.

Comment: Sorry thats what I'm doing.. I have that code in `show.js.erb` so that format should call both the `show.html.erb` and the `show.js.erb` however only the html gets called when I'm using that `respond_to` shown above in `simulation#show`

Comment: So I see what you mean, instead of rendering a view, just render a JS partial that has your code and renders the html partial, however whenever I go to 'show' a simulation, I get a request for html, not js, so I never execute that JS, how can I solve this ?

Comment: That is what I meant. You can have your js partial load with a `=render "partials/js_partial"` in your show page. Point you ajax in the partial to a different action.

Comment: So when I render the partial it gets rendered as html plain text, not as javascript, how can I tell it that its a javascript partial? Heres the line: `<%= render 'show.js.erb' %>`

Comment: An easy hack is to throw it in a script tag. Let me take a look in the A.M. and see if I have a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, will wait till then.

Comment: So using the script tag I got the render to poll correctly, thank you that helps a ton - Is there a less hacky way to place the javascript other then rendering it as a partial? Is this a hacky solution?

Comment: I'll see what I can figure out. I rarely do AJAX with rails tbh.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps  issue is with whatever calls the show action in the first place,
and it's missing the `remote: true` option ?

If its a link then try with `remote: true` option, something like :

`<%= link_to 'Show', simulation_path(my_simulation), remote: true %>`

same if its a button

`<%= button_to 'Show', simulation_path(my_simulation), remote: true %>`

This should cause Rails to call the controller with correct format and in logs you should see JS mentioned, e.g.

`Processing by SimulationsController#show as JS`

Also in the partial you are probably missing the dataType, try  :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/simulations/#{params}",
    dataType: "script"
})
```